# REGEX to find the value of id="findme" in a html element

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Given an HTML string like:

```
<span class="findme" id="31313131313">The Goods</span>
```

What kind of REGEX in Coldfusion would return just (if it's even possible?): 31313131313

Thanks!

Comment: You know regex shouldn't parse HTML right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags , and downvoted few people's answers, Do you still expecting something more?

Comment: Just trying to figure this out.

Comment: Erik, thanks but this is different, the last question was to get the SPAN... This question is how to extract the ID.

Comment: Any special reason why you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414576/coldfusion-regex-given-text-find-all-items-contained-in-spans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, `<span[^>]+?id="([^"]+)".*`

According to your comment in Amarghosh answer, that would be

```
<cfset uniqueID = rereplace(results[i],'<span[^>]+?id="([^"]+)".*',"\1")>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark,, just tried that, it's close... It's returning:

581-1268367477845>WTC Captive was created with a $1 billion FEMA grant and provides insurance coverage</span>

Comment: OK this did it! 
<cfset uniqueID = rereplace(results[i],'<span[^>]+?id="([^"]+)">(.*)',"\1")>

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to parse html using regex in general. Use an html parser instead.

That said, the following regex will give you the id **from the given string**.

```
<span[^>]*id="(\d+)"
```

The first group of the match, `$1`, will contain `31313131313`.

It assumes a numeric id. For alphanumeric ones, replace `\d` with `[0-9a-zA-Z]`. You can use `\w` if `_` is fine too.

Comment: @Amarghosh thxs, it will always be numeric. I just tried this but it returned the entire string, no change. Any ideas why?

Comment: Here is the full line: 
 <cfset uniqueID = rereplace(results[i], '<span[^>]*id="(\d+)"', '\3')>

Comment: Change `\3` to `\1` We've just one capturing group.

Comment: Just tried that:
<cfset uniqueID = rereplace(results[i], '<span[^>]*id="(\d+)"', '\1')>

Same reults, it is returning everything

Comment: I don't know CF, but try this: `<cfset uniqueID = rereplace(results[i], '.*<span[^>]*id="(\d+)".*', '\1')>`